# Scene Referred and Display Referred RGB values of the image

Tags: uv-image-editor

If I left click on an image in the UV/Image Editor two sets of RGB values are displayed. Are the "left" RGB values the scene referred values and the "right" RGB values the display referred values ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Right clicking (by default) doesn't do anything if you mean holding over the image and clicking.

Comment: I said left clicking :)

Comment: @OldMan do you mean x and y cursor location?

Comment: maybe I should say I use the filmic-blender config.ocio and luts as available here https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left values are scene referred values.

The right values, after the CM are post display referred transform.